# CDF of the distance of two random points on (0,1)

Tags: probability

Let $Y_1 \sim U(0,1)$ and $Y_2 \sim U(0,1)$.
Let $X = |Y_1 - Y_2|$.

Now the solution for the CDF in my book looks like this:

$P(X < t) = P(|Y_1 - Y_2| < t) = P(Y_2 - t < Y_1 < Y_2 + t) = 1-(1-t)^2$

They give this result without explanation. How do they come up with the $1-(1-t)^2$ part? Can you help me find the explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to change notation. Call the  random variable called $Y_1$ in the problem by the name $X$. Call the random variable called $Y_2$ in the problem by the name $Y$. And finally, call the random variable called $X$ in
 the problem by the name $T$. Trust me, these name changes are a good idea!

We need to assume that $X$ and $Y$ are **independent**.

Fix $t$ between $0$ and $1$. In the usual coordinate plane, draw the square with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$. Now draw the two lines $y=x+t$ and $y=x-t$. By independence, the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is uniform in our square.

Draw the lines $y=x-t$ and $y=x+t$. You know well what these look like. Remember that $0\le t \le 1$ when drawing the lines. For a nice picture, you could for example pick $t$ around $\frac{1}{3}$. (Without drawing a picture, you are unlikely to understand what is really going on.)

Note that $T\le t$ if and only if $|X-Y|\le t$ if and only if the pair $(X,Y)$ lands between our two lines. The probability that this happens is the **area** of the region between the two lines, divided by the area of the whole square, which is $1$. So we need to find the area of the region between the two lines.

Now we find that area.  The part of the square which is **outside** our region consists of two isosceles right-angled triangles. Each of these triangles has legs $1-t$, so together they make up a $(1-t)\times (1-t)$ square, with area $(1-t)^2$.

Thus the area of the region between the two lines is $1-(1-t)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a picture.  In the $y_1 y_2$ plane, the region where $|y_1 - y_2| < t$ (where $0 < t < 1$) looks like this:

[image]

What is its area?

Comment: (+1)Area of the green region is the required answer and it will be $1-2\times \frac{1}{2}(1-t)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $P[-t<Y_1-Y_2<t]=P[(Y_1,Y_2)\in A]$ where $A=\{(y_1,y_2)|-t<y_1-y_2<t\}$.

Again note that $P[(Y_1,Y_2)\in A]=\text{Area of A}=1-(1-t)^2$. You need to draw a graph and need to find the area of A.